# Is there a word for enjoying the entertainment surrounding the election?

Tags: single-word-requests, politics, government

I have heard of *electiontainment*, which I like as a word-geek. Yet, it only returned 400 results on Google. Is there anything similar that has wider penetration?

Comment: For this election I think *electionainment* /eleksh-*inane*-ment/ is better.

Comment: In Britain, thank the Lord, most people still hesitate to abuse the English language with such ridiculous words. Coinage also tends to stereotype thought processes, in my view. Who is to say where genuine political interest ends and so-called *entertainment* starts?

Comment: A campaign is all about crafting entertainment. You're just doing what they hope you will do - Appreciating mediocrity at it's finest. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tly8abRH4ws

Comment: @Jim *electinsanement* is the more appropriate term.

Comment: @HotLicks - Yeah, I didn't fully appreciate the depth of it back then.